# Can I render a component in client site when use angular 2 server side rendering

Tags: angularjs, angular, asp.net-core, server-side-rendering

Because I get error with "Call to Node module failed with error: ReferenceError: window is not defined". So I want one of my components render in client site. Is it possible?

I 'm use "aspnetcore-spa generator" to generate project (http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/)

Answer (score 0):

Now, I still don't know how to render a component in client site, but if you get error server side as "window is not defined" or something like that, you can fix by put all your directives, providers (which make this errors) to file `boot-client.ts`.

```
bootstrap(App, [
HTTP_PROVIDERS,
FormBuilder,
provideRouter(routes),
GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS,
provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: [...RESPONSIVE_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIVES, TextEllipsis, NgSwitch, NgSwitchCase, NgSwitchDefault, StyledMapDirective, Map], multi: true }),
provide(PLATFORM_PIPES, { useValue: [pipe.ImageUrl, pipe.ModelClass, pipe.ModelName], multi: true })]);
```

Anyone have another answer